# Select related field before the field itself - Odoo 8

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8, many2one

I'm working on **Odoo 8** and i have 3 tables : bloc, floor and room

with floor having a many2one relation with bloc, and room having a many2one relation with floor

when creating a room record, i want to select the bloc first so i can load floors in that bloc only, but without having a many2one relation between room and bloc, since it'd be redundant

is there a way to do that?

i tried to look for a way to group the floors by bloc in the selection but even that couldn't work.

Comment: You want to select a bloc when creating a room without having a relation between bloc and room, please can you explain more?

Comment: room has a many2one relation with floor, and floor has a many2one relation with bloc

when creating the room i need to select the floor it's in, but i want to show the floors based on bloc, so first u select bloc then select floor, but i don't want to store the bloc id in the room table since i can get it from the floor later on

Comment: Would you consider creating rooms from the bloc view

Comment: No that wouldn't be a case for me, I'm aware that if i add a link i can have it both direction

Answer (score 1):

You can use a related field and use it in the floor field domain to filter out blocs.

Related fields are not stored by default, they are computed and returned when requested (Odoo will not create a database column in the room table)

***Example:***

- Room model

  ```
  class Room(models.Model):
      _name = 'room.room'

      floor_id = fields.Many2one('floor.floor')
      bloc_id = fields.Many2one(related="floor_id.bloc_id")
  ```
- Form view

  ```
  <field name="floor_id" domain="[('bloc_id', '=', bloc_id)]"/>
  ```

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for your reply and your time.

Unfortunately, it did not work for me, is it logical? if the bloc is related to the floor then you have to set the floor value before the bloc

Comment: I tested it and it works. The related field will compute the value of the bloc to be the same as the floor's bloc and Odoo will let you select the bloc field value before setting the floor (the field is editable), this is what makes it possible to use it in the floor field domain.

Comment: The bloc gives you floors so it comes first